# Can you detect the HTML 5 History API on the server side?

Tags: html

Is there reliable a way to detect such browser capability from the user agent string?

Answer (score 1):

HTML5 isn't a server-side language.

Anyway, there isn't a way to reliably detect UA capabilities, for instance they could have Javascript turned off, addons installed, etc. etc.

You could use some SS methods such as [PHP's Browser Detect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php), but aside from that there's nothing more you can really do. This is not at all comprehensive at all, though!

Everything such as this should really be done client side in Javascript, as you can easily detect what's available and what isn't. There's a number of libraries out there that will do this, but it's very simple to do yourself if you know what you want so using one shouldn't really be required. Furthermore, you should never want to do this based on User Agent strings, as I mentioned before there's addons available that *can* modify behaviour etc. You should literally just check for the feature you wish to use rather than restricting yourself to a certain version of the browser.

Comment: Thanks. I'm well aware that HTML 5 is not related to the server, but it would be great to decide if the client needs eg. redirection based on his browser's capability. This can be especially important when a site's navigation is implemented using the History API, so when I visit `/foo/bar` directly, the server redirects me to `/#/foo/bar` if my browser is a dumb one. (And vice versa, of course)

It could save a great deal of bandwidth, not having to download any JS at all, doing it with a simple redirect header.

Comment: Oh I see, not really sure if you could even do this. Have you seen an example where it has been done before??

Comment: Not yet. But I guess this is due to the fact that very few sites are using the API yet. GitHub is one example, but they simply fall back to traditional navigation instead of a [hashmark-based](http://sammyjs.org) one.

Answer (score 1):

Not reliably — you’re stuck with figuring out the browser version from the user-agent string, and maintaining a list of which browser versions support the API.

You could, however, detect it on the client side using JavaScript:

- [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)
- [Mark Pilgrim’s suggested History API detection code](http://diveintohtml5.info/everything.html#history)

and then do a redirect via JavaScript (i.e. by setting `window.location`) to let the server know whether the API is available or not. That would be the usual way to redirect to a URL starting with `#` (as per your comment on [rudi_visser’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867032/can-you-detect-the-html-5-history-api-on-the-server-side/5867065#5867065).

Answer (score 0):

This is not server side (so it probably does not answer your question, I thought it would be helpful though):

Have you looked at [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)

It is a javascript file you include in your HTML page. You can then use its properties to detect if a particular HTML 5 tag is supported by the browser.

Comment: Thank you. I know about Modernizr (and I use it extensively), but to determine what to serve to a client in a first place is a great thing to have. Thats why I asked about server-side solutions specifically.